# Getting error while try to color my turtle

Tags: python, python-turtle

```
from turtle import Turtle
my_turtle = Turtle()
my_turtle.color(40.0, 80.0, 120.0)
my_turtle.forward(50)
```

The code works well when I try to work with str such as .color("green") or .color("#285078"), but while I work with the 3 int I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python Projects\Practice\Day 18\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    my_turtle.color(40.0, 80.0, 120.0)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 2217, in color
    pcolor = self._colorstr(pcolor)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 2697, in _colorstr
    return self.screen._colorstr(args)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 1167, in _colorstr
    raise TurtleGraphicsError("bad color sequence: %s" % str(color))
turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: bad color sequence: (40.0, 80.0, 120.0)
```

Comment: Try `(40,80,120)`; 40.0, 80.0 and 120.0 aren't `int`s.

Comment: @madprops The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.color) says you can pass either a tuple or separate arguments

Comment: You need to use `turtle.colormode(255)` to allow numbers in the range 0-255.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Screen` object and set its `colormode` to `255` which on default was set to `1.0`.

```
from turtle import Screen

my_screen = Screen()
my_screen.colormode(255)
```

Now pass the arguments of `my_turtle.color()` of integer datatype.

```
my_turtle.color(40, 80, 120)
```

**Note:** At the end of the program, add this line which lets you exit the window after a click, or else it closes automatically as soon it's opened.

```
my_screen.exitonclick()
```